# Adding an active low pass filter to circuit changes voltage from 2-3V (0.5v amplitude) to 'dc' 2.5v but doesn't when separate

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, active-filter

I have circuit that contains a summing amplifier as well as other components previous to it. I am trying to add an active low pass filter to limit frequencies above 50Hz. It works perfectly on it own, however when added to the complete circuit after the summing amplifier, the voltage drops from a 2-3v sinusoidal wave form to a 'dc' 2.5v. I have built this circuit in proteus to test the functionality. Below is the lowpass filter separate from the full circuit. I have also added a simple RC filter to the end of this circuit, as without this the filter was letting through very high frequencies due to the high output impedance of the op amp.
[image: Low Pass Filter]

These waveforms show the correct operation of the filter.

[image: Waveforms]

Here is the filter in the complete circuit.

[image: Filter in Circuit]

And the waveform showing the incorrect output voltage when the filter is connected to the whole circuit.

[image: Incorrect voltage waveforms]

How would I fix this circuit to have the correct voltage output when using the low pass filter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 6.8 farad capacitor in the final RC filter will just make the cutoff frequency extremely low. It may be off by a factor of 1e6.

Try 6.8 microfarads like in the non-final circuit.

Comment: Wow, that is so frustrating. I looked at that for like an hour and the only problem was a simple typo, a missing u. ugh. thanks very much for the second set of eyes!

Answer (score -1):

Replace the 54 years old 741 opamp that has trouble above only 9kHz with a modern opamp that works perfectly up to 100kHz. Your schematic had its parts so far apart that it was hard to see. I cropped it.
[image: active lowpass]